# risolvere path python 3?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, path

I'm at the first approaches with python. I'm having problems. Basically it's a script that I have to use on my pc. Help.

in addition to the problem of the path, I would like to replace the sleep method with a method that starts another one at the end of that process.thanks

```
import os
import time 
import numpy


site_name=input("""Insert domain: example.com
>>>""")
                
file_name=input(str("insert file name(.txt):"))

pathname = os.path.join("/home", "andrea3", "Scrivania/")
f=open (pathname+file_name,"x")








os.popen("amass enum -passive -d "+ site_name + " |tee "+ file_name)
time.sleep(30)
#with open ("/home/andrea3/Scrivania/"+ file_name, "r+")
f_arr=pathname+f.readlines()

n_arr=numpy.array(f_arr)





for line in f_arr:
    os.popen("cat " + file_name + "|amass enum -passive -d " + line + ">>" + file_name)
    time.sleep(40)
```

in addition to the problem of the path, I would like to replace the sleep method with a method that starts another one at the end of that process.thanks